# Tel href link stops working on iPhone in Web App mode

Tags: iphone, url, href, web-applications, tel

I have a fairly simple HTML page with a link on it that calls a phone number.

```
<a href="tel:1234567890%2C%2C9#">Call Us<a/>
```

The idea is to call the number 1234567890, have two pauses, then dial 9 followed by the pound symbol.

This works fine when viewing the page in Mobile Safari. The confirmation displays and you can call the number.

If I enable Web App mode (using apple-mobile-web-app-capable) and add it to my home screen, the link stops working. As soon as I remove the # at the end the link starts working again.

I've tried various things but the link simply stops responding to a click no matter what as long as it contains the # symbol. Is this some sort of security restriction since in Web App mode it no longer asks for confirmation to dial a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.
Did you came up with a solution?
It must be possible to find a workaround because when I'm dialing such a number from my contacts the # character is not a problem.

Edit: it appears to be an Apple security measure:
[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)!

Comment: Do you have another way to get to this document? The link doesn't appear to work. (I never did find a solution)

Comment: I had no problem fallowing this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: Accepting since it does explain why it doesn't work, even though the # works fine in Mobile Safari (which it seems shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

try use \u0023 instead of a plain #

Comment: Using the URL encoded version (%23) doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: # is not support by iOS tel: url according to Apple document